# File appears on network share with delay

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, windows-server-2012-r2

I have sent a text file to a network share of my home Windows Server 2012 R2 PC. All of the Windows 7 PCs see this file immediately except one, which sees it around five minutes later.

What is happening?

Comment: Sry, my bagde is to small for comment: Helps this?
https://serverfault.com/questions/482174/slow-shared-folder-refresh-on-windows-7

Comment: @SavGuard: Yes, it seems to be the case.